# Customising context menus in Android 

Tags: android

Is there a way to change the look and feel of a context menu?
I want to add my own background, list item seperator and maybe the selector as well.
I want to change it in famework so that i will get the customised menu every where i will use it.

Can someone point me in the right direction? As far as I could make
out - Context menu is just an alert dialog with a list. Am I right? How can i change the look and feel and from where?

Answer (score 2):

Be tricky: I have done that by starting an activity with the dialog theme instead of inflating a context menu in `onCreateContextMenu`. So you can style it the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You will more than likely have to look up that class java file in the android kernel repo and modify it to get what you want.